# Error while installing e(fx)clipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, installation, efxclipse

Calculating requirements and dependencies takes very long time and got this [strange request to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC2GI.png)
And during installing time this comes
[Install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBFQK.png)
Full text:
`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=C__Users_Диас_Desktop_JAVA_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Result of processing steps.     OK OK OK Public key not found for -9147676190077153272. OK Result of processing steps. OK OK OK Public key not found for -9147676190077153272. OK`

My eclipse version:
Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Build id: 20210612-2011

Does someone have same problem ?
What I can do?

Comment: I would start by uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling it. It that doesn't work, I would uninstall Eclipse and reinstall Eclipse and the plugin.

Comment: It's been a while since I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ. I remember an error like this (though I can't be sure if it's exactly the same). I think I resolved it by selecting a very minimal part of E(fx)clipse, which included the basic plugins etc.